# Existence of maximizer implies compact?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, continuity, compactness

I know that compact sets imply the existence of a maximizer, but is the converse true:

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space. Suppose that whenever $f$ is a continuous (and real) function on $X$, there exists a point $y \in X$ such that $f(y) \geq f(x)$ for all $x \in X$. Then X is compact.

Comment: It seems not, since no bounds from below follow (take $X=(-\infty,0]$).

Comment: ^That doesn't work, since the function $f(x)=-x$ on $(-\infty, 0]$ has no maximum.

Comment: (I don't think that the observation "by applying the statement to $|f|$, any real-valued function on $X$ is bounded" warrants having a whole new question)

Answer (score 3):

If $X$ is metric and not compact, then $X$ has an infinite closed discrete subset $D$. By passing to a subset if necessary, we may assume that $D=\{x_n:n\in\Bbb N\}$ is countably infinite. Now define $f:D\to\Bbb R:x_n\mapsto n$, and apply the [Tietze extension theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tietze_extension_theorem) to get an unbounded continuous real-valued function on $X$.